# Why is elif not registering when I run the code? Simple Dice Game

Tags: python, random

I'm making a dice game for practice. The computer (ai) rolls dice against the player and then the results are compared for who is the winner. However, when both of the results are the same (e.g. player rolls a 4 and ai rolls a 4) the program says "you win!" even though I put in an elif statement for a tie. Any help?

---

```
import random
import time

player = random.randint(1,6)
print("You rolled " + str(player))

ai = random.randint(1,6)
print("The computer rolls...")
time.sleep(2)
print("The computer has rolled a " + str(player))

if player > ai:
 print("You win")

elif player == ai:
 print("Tie game")

else: 
 print("You lose")
```

---

I've already tried to put else before elif but then I get a syntax error?

Comment: And how do you know the results are the same? There is a typo in print statement. You are printing results of player instead of ai

Comment: You are not displaying the ai roll, you are displaying the player roll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for the comparisons is correct, what is incorrect is that you display twice the score of the player. This making it look like both player and ai have the same roll, while in fact they might be different.

```
ai = random.randint(1,6)
print("The computer rolls...")
time.sleep(2)
print("The computer has rolled a " + str(player)) # here
```

You should display that of the ai:

```
ai = random.randint(1,6)
print("The computer rolls...")
time.sleep(2)
print("The computer has rolled a " + str(ai))
```